# missing key column in results of pandas groupby filter

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas groupby object:

```
routeGroups = tracking.groupby(tracking.columns[0])
```

Then I apply a filter:

```
filterFunc = lambda x: np.any(np.isfinite(x['LAT']))
results = routeGroups.filter(filterFunc)
```

`results` is a dataframe, but the column used to create the group by `tracking.columns[0]` is missing in the dataframe.

This behavior seems to be inconsistent..sometimes it is missing and sometimes it is not. I am not sure what is going on, or what a work around could be.

Comment: The answer below is relevant when doing aggregation on groups. I can't reproduce your behavior when doing filtering. Can you post a working example?

Comment: well I can't share the data.  I can perform `routeGroups.sum()` and see that the index is 'SHIPMENT NUMBER' (which is the column I grouped by). But when I try this filter:

    `filterFunc = lambda x: np.any(np.isfinite(x[nanCol]))`
    `tntFiltered = (routes.filter(filterFunc))`

`tntFiltered` does not have that column. I will post the answer here if I figure out why this is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If doing aggregation, the column used for grouping will be the index of `results`.

To avoid this behavior you can either

1. pass `as_index=False` to the `groupby` function (`routeGroups = tracking.groupby(tracking.columns[0],as_index=False`)
2. use `results.reset_index()`

For filtering, the default behavior seems to be to keep the column (see comment).